# TypeError: Cannot create property 'lastUpdateCheck' on string 'lastUpdateCheck 1599160669280'

Tags: php, homebrew, yarnpkg, macos-catalina

So I'm getting this error when I try to do a yarn install. I can yarn start without issue but i'm not sure if it's causing an issue behind the scenes so i'd like to resolve it.

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'lastUpdateCheck' on string 'lastUpdateCheck 1599160669280'
at YarnRegistry.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:96344:30)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:328:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new F (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
at YarnRegistry.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:307:12)
at YarnRegistry.saveHomeConfig (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:96351:20)
at Install.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.5/libexec/lib/cli.js:7930:35)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

i've tried deleting my yarn.lock and basically every file i could find that had yarn in it and reinstalling. I've tried installing yarn through yvm instead of brew. None of these things have had any affect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you more details about how yarn got installed and how I can reproduce the issue? It would be great that you can attach some github repo.

Comment: I can't provide the repo but it was installed through a brew yarn. I didn't make any modifications to the yarn files before receiving the issue. I have version yarn install v1.22.5.

Comment: let me try it in my local.

Comment: I'm experiencing this with WSL. Are you using brew with WSL?

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried removing the `~/.yarnrc` file? I had a corrupted `.yarnrc` file that was preventing me from installing.

Running this should remove your yarnrc.

```sh
rm ~/.yarnrc
```

Experienced this issue with WSL but it should be applicable in other cases.

I also submitted and later resolved an issue [8469](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8469)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got with the brewed yarn (v1.22.5):

### installation test

- `yarn init`
- `yarn add test`

```
$ yarn init
yarn init v1.22.5
question name (brew-test):
question version (1.0.0):
question description:
question entry point (index.js):
question repository url:
question author:
question license (MIT):
question private:
success Saved package.json
✨  Done in 2.16s.
```

```
$ yarn add test
yarn add v1.22.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 2 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ test@0.6.0
info All dependencies
├─ ansi-font@0.0.2
└─ test@0.6.0
✨  Done in 0.55s.
```

### brew config

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.5.0-123-g58cb2ce
ORIGIN: git@github.com:Homebrew/brew.git
HEAD: 58cb2ce5bc1bb262c168483024bf80b147a0e86f
Last commit: 3 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
Core tap HEAD: 4421467f40a0eb970135644cfb4c403df015a43f
Core tap last commit: 6 minutes ago
Core tap branch: bzt-1.5.0
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.QcT5vipIW7/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_EDITOR: vim
HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: set
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit kabylake
Clang: 11.0 build 1100
Git: 2.27.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 11.0.6, 1.8.0_265, 1.8.0_192, 1.8.0_181, 1.8.0_65
macOS: 10.14.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
Xcode: 11.2.1
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while I was trying to set up a Chakra-UI project with Vite and Reactjs but mine was throwing a different error code - MODULE_NOT_FOUND. I noticed this when I ran the command `yarn` to install dependencies. When I ran `yarn --version` to be sure if I still had yarn enabled the error was still there, even by just running `yarn` it was still throwing the same error code. I enabled yarn using `corepack enable` and updated to the latest version with the command `yarn set version stable` and `yarn install` - yarn docs, here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install   . I noticed this problem was resolved when I deleted a hidden yarn configuration file called `.yarnrc` that lives in my root directory; where I performed the yarn installation. If you're on Linux the command `ls -a` can be used to view hidden files in a directory. What I don't understand is why that `.yarnrc` file was preventing me from using yarn? I had to delete it before yarn started working. When run `yarn` again; another new `.yarnrc` file was created but not causing any issues. Maybe the old one was corrupted. See the image below for the error. [image: yarn module_error screenshot]Thank you.